# <iframe> rendering outside of it's <div> container?

Tags: html, css, iframe, embed, vimeo

Slightly baffled here. Is there something wrong with my code or does this suggest a JS/PHP conflict or iframe bug i'm simply not aware of...?

The following iframe (vimeo embed) is consistently rendering outside of it's container div.

**This HTML mark-up:**

```html
<div class="slider">

  <!--- Image --->
  <div class="single-event-image-bg tb-overlay single-event-slides" style="background-image:url(<?php echo tribe_event_featured_image( null, 'large', false, false ); ?>);">
  </div>

  <!-- Video -->
  <div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe id="single-event-video" class="single-event-video" width="668" height="415" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/320740213" frameborder="0" mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Is rendering this:**

[image]

I've tried using different tags, removing php, class names and deactivating the javascript slider i'm trying to make it work inside of. Even without any of the above it is still rendering outside of the div.

**CSS on iframe is simply:**

```
iframe { display: block; position: relative; width:100% max-width:100% }
```

EDIT: Have tested on CodePen and StackOverflow run snippet. The markup seems to be working fine. So issue is limited to our site, any thoughts on what might be causing this behaviour? 
Thanks

Comment: RESOLVED: I'm not entirely sure why but removing the element ID from a parent container resolved this issue. The ID was not being used by any CSS or Javascript I could locate nor was it a common ID name. However there must have been a conflict with something targeting the ID name somewhere which in turn affected the iframe mark-up.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED:** I'm still not entirely sure why but removing the element ID from a parent container resolved this issue. The ID was not being used by any CSS or Javascript I could locate nor was it a common ID name. However there must have been a conflict with something targeting the ID name somewhere which in turn affected the iframe mark-up.